# define constants paths in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, constants

I'm trying to this in laravel app folder:

```
define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', /paypal/sdk_config.ini);
```

The source of this is a file i created next to routes.php and filters.php and i named it constants.php.

in the laravel app folder i have a folder named paypal and inside it i have the sdk_config,

i recieve this all the time:

```
Use of undefined constant paypal - assumed 'paypal'
Open: C:\wamp\www\misterSurvey\app\constants.php
<?php
    define('PP_CONFIG_PATH',/paypal/sdk_config.ini);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encapsulate the string within ' or " otherwise it will try looking for constants, and you will get a `Use of undefined constant` error. Like so;

```
define('PP_CONFIG_PATH','/paypal/sdk_config.ini');
```

**Note**: This is an error within the documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php   that mean they made a mistake?  Copy the sample configuration file sdk_config.ini to a location of your choice and let the SDK know your config path using the following define directive.
    define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', /path/to/your/sdk_config.ini);

Comment: Indeed this is a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You need to always put strings into quotes (single or double depending on need) otherwise you will get errors `Use of undefined constant`.

For example:

```
$x = aaa;
```

you will also get this error because there are no quotes before and after `aaa` so the correct usage is:

```
$x = 'aaa';
```

The same is in your case. It should be:

```
define('PP_CONFIG_PATH', '/paypal/sdk_config.ini');
```

It seems there is error in documentation at https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php - quotes should be there or it's rather some pseudo path so author didn't add quotes because it's obvious.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
//file : app/config/constants.php

return [
    'PP_CONFIG_PATH' => '/paypal/sdk_config.ini'
];
```

in anywhere:

```
echo Config::get('constants.PP_CONFIG_PATH');
```